# Moving Media files to S3 bucket

Tags: magento2, media

I want **AWS CloudFront** to be implemented in production for a Magento 2 site.

I would like to know what changes are required to change the path of **images and audio/ video files**, to set up on S3 bucket.

Please note that the site will remain same, its just the media files will be moved to **S3 bucket on AWS**.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on below code :

https://github.com/thaiphan/magento2-s3

You can find configuration steps on https://github.com/thaiphan/magento2-s3/wiki/Installation

Comment: Mine is magento2.3, which is not supported by this extension. Is there any other way rather than extension

Comment: @StevenHarris have you found any extension which is compatable with magento2.3?

Comment: No.............